# Integration of Sustainsys.Saml2 in plain Asp.Net Core MVC web app

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I am trying to integrate Azure AD SSO with the Sustainsys Saml2 library.
I have created Enterpise application in Azure. When I click on `Test single sign-on` the authentication is successfull and I am redirected to  `LoginCallback` method where I have to parse the response but it is not clear how to do this using Sustainsys.Saml2?

Second issue i have is that no matter where the `RedirectUri` is setup, the application (not Azure dashboard) after the successfull login always redirects to `https://localhost:44354/Saml2/Acs` instead of `https://localhost:44354/Account/LoginCallback`

I have tried to follow the .netcore sample in the library repo but it utilizes the ASP Identity which i am trying to avoid. Therefore I have created plain ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC web application and added via nuget Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 2.3.0 version. In Startup.cs I defined the following configuration:

```
 services.AddAuthentication()
          .AddSaml2(Saml2Defaults.Scheme, options =>
          {
              options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("IDName");
              options.SPOptions.ReturnUrl = new Uri($"https://localhost:44364/Account/LoginCallback"); // always get ignored and set as Saml2/Asc
              options.IdentityProviders.Add(
                  new IdentityProvider(
                      new EntityId("https://sts.windows.net/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/"), options.SPOptions)
                  {
                      LoadMetadata = true,
                      MetadataLocation = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/aaaaaaaaa/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                  });

              //options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("Sustainsys.Saml2.Tests.pfx"));
          });
```

Next, I have created an Account controller with two methods:

```
    [HttpGet("Login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(
            Saml2Defaults.Scheme,
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                // It looks like this parameter is ignored, so I set ReturnUrl in Startup.cs
                //RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(LoginCallback), "Account", new { returnUrl })
            });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginCallback( string returnUrl)
    {
       // How do I parse the response (saml) from body

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second part of your question,  if you are still struggling, you want to do something like What is shown here in the first code block :

[AuthenticateResult.Succeeded is false with Okta and Sustainsys.SAML2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853661/authenticateresult-succeeded-is-false-with-okta-and-sustainsys-saml2)